# Alinear con bootstrap textarea y boton de submit

Tags: html, bootstrap, wordpress, contact-form-7

Estoy tratando de colocar un text area al lado del boton de enviar, pero por alguna razón por mas que pruebe a crear columnas y filas siempre aparece debajo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando contact form 7 de wordpress Este sería el código usado:

```
<div class="row shorten">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
    <div class="input-filled radius">
      [text* your-name placeholder "Nombre"]
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="input-filled radius">
      [text* your-phone placeholder "Telefono "]
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
    <div class="input-filled radius">
      [email* your-email placeholder "Email "]
    </div>
    <br />
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-3">
    [textarea* your-message x1 class:form-control placeholder "Mensaje"]
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-3">
    <button type="submit" class="wpcf7-submit btn radius">▷</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

También he probado:

```
<div class="row shorten">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
    <div class="input-filled radius">
      [text* your-name placeholder "Nombre"]
    </div>
    <div class="input-filled radius">
      [text* your-phone placeholder "Telefono "]
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
    <div class="input-filled radius">
      [email* your-email placeholder "Email "]
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="input-filled radius">
        [textarea* your-message x1 class:form-control placeholder "Mensaje"]
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <button type="submit" class="wpcf7-submit btn col-12 col-sm-12 radius">▷</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

no se muy bien porque no puedo colocarlo paralelo es decir[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo por aquí una solución usando css, junté el boton y el textArea en el mismo div y les asigne un float left:

HTML

```
<div class="row shorten">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
    <div class="input-filled radius">
      [text* your-name placeholder "Nombre"]
    </div>
    <div class="input-filled radius">
      [text* your-phone placeholder "Telefono "]
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
    <div class="input-filled radius">
      [email* your-email placeholder "Email "]
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="input-filled radius textArea">
        [textarea* your-message x1 class:form-control placeholder "Mensaje"]
      </div>
      <button
        type="submit"
        class="wpcf7-submit btn col-12 col-sm-12 radius boton"
      >
        ▷
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>;
```

CSS

```
.boton, .textArea{
  float: left;
}
```

Espero que te sirva y ten un buen dia!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! el problema es que se me queda el text area muy pequeño, he tenido que colocarle un tamaño y al ampliar o reducir la página se va abajo otra vez.

Comment: para eso tienes que jugar con los col-xs, me olvidé de cambiártelo a 12, el div donde esta tu textArea con el botón esta en **col-xs-6**, ve jugando con las [rejillas](https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/bootstrap-3/capitulo-2/tipos-de-rejillas) y encontraras la solución

Comment: Gracias, aunque si lo puse en 12 y seguía saliendo mas pequeño.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba meter el mensaje y el botón dentro de un div con la clase "row", así se quedarían en la misma fila pero además, controla que el tamaño de ambos div(mensaje y botón) sean un poco menos que 12, porque estás usando un col-sm-3. Al darle ese margen estás tomando espacio de otra col (por eso no puede dar 12 la suma de las 2 porque se te baja el botón).
Modifiqué el código que pasaste al principio haciendo lo que te explico. Pruébalo y me cuentas. Un saludo!

```
<div class="row shorten">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="input-filled radius">
          [text* your-name placeholder "Nombre"]
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="input-filled radius">
          [text* your-phone placeholder "Telefono "]
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="input-filled radius">
          [email* your-email placeholder "Email "]
        </div>
        <br />
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-9 col-sm-3">
        [textarea* your-message x1 class:form-control placeholder "Mensaje"]
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 col-sm-3">
        <button type="submit" class="wpcf7-submit btn radius">▷</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```